# Convert CSS variables to SCSS variables

Tags: css, regex, replace, visual-studio-code, find

I am in the process of changing all my css files to scss. Howevever, I need to convert css variables to scss variables for all my styling files.

Is there a way I can do this without going into each file and using find and replace? I am using VS code as was thinking of using the find and replace with a regex expression like. But I cannot get it to work.

```
\(.*?\)i
```

For example convert

```
// css 
.blog {
  box-shadow: var(--lightShadow);
  transition: var(--mainTransition);
}
```

into

```
// scss
.blog {
  box-shadow: $lightShadow;
  transition: $mainTransition;
}
```

Comment: Try `\bvar\(--(\w+)\)` and replace with `$$$1`. Or  `\bvar\(--([^()]+)\)`

Comment: Side question, as I am in a similar situation: does migrating to SCSS instead of relying upon CSS variables give so much benefits?

Comment: @EmanueleDelGrande I think it makes things more readable and easier to work with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

**Find What**:      `\bvar\(--(\w+)\)` (or `\bvar\(--([^()]+)\)`)
**Replace With**: `$$$1`

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `var\(--` - `var(--` string
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: 1+ letters, digits or underscores (`[^()]+` matches 1+ chars other than `(` and `)`)
- `\)` - a `)` char.

The `$$$1` replaces with a dollar symbol and the value inside Group 1.

Demo:

[image]